# Custom Attribute Ending

Tags: attributes

I have custom attributes, such as "Carats" - these are whole numbers, I want to avoid storing the data as a text field like "14 Cts" or "14 Ct" due to the ease of the data becoming de-normalized over time.

Ideally I would like them to be stored as number columns, but how can I add "Cts" to the displaying of these columns everywhere on the frontend with ease?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you'll need to add some code, using the translation functionalities provided by Magento.

Lookup the file `frontend\base\default\template\catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`, this is the phtml file you'll need to edit for this. Copy it to your local template directory and edit it.

Go to line `46`, there the value is outputted. Replace

```
<td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
```

with

```
<td class="data"><?php echo $this->__('%d attr_' . $_data['code'], (int)$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])) ?></td>
```

Let's say your attribute code is `carats`, the Magento translate function will now look for the string `%d attr_carats` in the translation CSVs. All you need to do now is add this string to the local translation CSV like this `"%d attr_carats","%d Cts"` and you will get the right label outputted in the attributes table in the Product detail page.

You can do this for every attribute you want to add a suffix to.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to achieve this partially, so not only for decimal attributes.
When I follow your guiding, the decimal fields are showing up correctly :)

[image: Screenshot]

But how do I achieve this for the non-decimal attributes? When I don't submit a translation line, it gives a number with 'attr_****' after it.
I hope you or someone has a solution for me :) And maybe tell me if it's required to add all of the attributes to the local translation file.